# Identifying 3 sides of a polygon.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

When identifying opposite sides of polygons we obtain a surface. For instance, the torus can be obtained by gluing together opposite sides of a square.

I saw a claim that if we identify 3 sides of a polygon then we do not obtain a surface. I don't see why this is true?

Could anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Intuitively, identifying three sides would cause the "surface" to not be locally a 2-manifold at the line of identification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you identify three sides of a polygon, then locally along the identified side you get a space that looks like three half-planes glued together along their boundary.  You can visualize it as $\mathsf{Y}\times\mathbb{R}$ where $\mathsf{Y}$ is a space shaped like the letter Y (in other words, three line segments glued together at a point).  That's not locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (though it takes some work to prove this rigorously), so it's not a surface.

This is in contrast to what happens when you identify two sides: then you get two half-planes glued together, which form one whole plane, so it is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: What do you call such an object if not a surface? I am interested in learning more about them (have they been classified etc)

Comment: It's worth also noting that despite not being surfaces you can still try to create "coloring" theorems on such objects made using triple identification etc...

Comment: There's not really any special name for it.  It's just some 2-dimensional cell complex.